# Proguard error : No such file or directory

Tags: android

I am receiving this exception while creation of signed apk of my application.

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\xx\Desktop\APP\xx\Users\imac\Amit\Workspace\xx\libs\universal-image-loader-1.9.4.jar] (No such file or directory)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178)
    at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:100)
    at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:196)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:50)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: removed JS snippet

Comment: removed please help from title